# Bing maps v8 pin position is off when zoomed

Tags: internet-explorer-10, bing-maps

I am using [Bing Maps V8](http://www.bing.com/api/maps/sdkrelease/mapcontrol/isdk#overview) web API. It works fine when using all latest version of modern browsers. It does not plot the pins correctly. The pins are off from the original position.

Zoomed in:
[image]

Zoomed Out:
[image]

All of the pin locations are supposed to be inside the land area. But when zooming out, the pin never updates its location.

Is there anything I am missing? Is there any update event to be fired when map zooms?

Thanks
Senthil S

Comment: Small note, the Bing Maps V8 is a Web based control/api. The Bing Maps REST API's are something different.

Answer (score 1):

To fix the issue, I had to add the "anchor" to options when creating Pushpin object as said in this post

[Properly Anchoring Pushpins](http://www.bing.com/api/maps/sdkrelease/mapcontrol/isdk#properlyAnchoringPushpins+JS)